# PHP access array within XML

Tags: php, xml

I have a PHP script that loads an XML sheet like so:

```
$feed = 'mydata.xml';
$xml = file_get_contents($feed);
$data = simplexml_load_string($xml);

echo print_r($data);
```

The result looks like this (although I've chopped a lot out):

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [merchant] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => companyname
                )

            [prod] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                         (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                     [id] => 690579815
                                     [lang] => en
                                     [pre_order] => no
                                     [web_offer] => yes
                                     [in_stock] => yes
                                )
```

My question is, how can I access the **prod** array?
I want to be able to count it like so:

```
count($data['prod']);
```

And also get particular field values but I'm quite new to PHP and XML and can't quite do it.

Thanks!

Comment: `$data` is not an array, it's an instance of `SimpleXMLElement`, use it accordingly: `$data->merchant->prod[0];`

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, how can I access the prod array?

You can't. Because there is no array. But it's okay you ask, it's just `print_r` has been fooling you a little. **SimpleXMLElement** is an object and it can change what will be shown when it gets `print_r`'ed and it fakes you some arrays there.

Some basics to the rescue:

`$data` represents the document element of the XML you have. In case you're in doubt what's in the XML, instead of `print_r` look into `$data->asXML()` (if you look through your browser view source or hint the output as plain-text otherwise the browser will hide all tags).

`$data['prod']` gives you the attribute named *prod*  on that document element. As there is none, it returns `null`:

```
var_dump($data['prod']);   ---   NULL
```

And the `count` of `NULL` is 0:

```
var_dump(count(NULL));     ---   int(0)
```

You neither want to look into the document element nor do you want to look-up attributes. You're interested in the child-elements named *prod* inside the *merchant* element.

So first obtain the first *merchant* element:

```
$merchant = $data->merchant;
```

You obtain elements with object access, that is with the object operator `->`.

And the get the count of the number of child elements named *prod*:

```
var_dump(count($merchant->prod));   ---   int(3)
```

As this shows, I've got three (3) children named *prod*  inside the *merchant* element represented by `$merchant`.

So you don't need any array here, the **SimpleXMLElement** allows you access to all the XML-elements inside the XML document.

As written earlier, the array brackets are used for [array-access](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php). So it looks like an array, but it is actually an object. It has been used to access the attributes. But this is only true, if the key is not a number. If it's a number, it will access the n-th named element:

```
var_dump($merchant->prod[0]->asXML());
```

Will give the XML of the first *prod* element of the *merchant* element:

> `string(94) "<prod id="690579815" lang="en" pre_order="no" web_offer="yes" in_stock="yes">product #1</prod>"`

As it is the first element, you can obtain it's *id* attribute as well:

```
var_dump($merchant->prod[0]['id']->asXML());
```

Which returns exactly that attribute:

> `string(15) " id="690579815""`

But it does not stop here. Each of these **SimpleXMLElement** objects of XML elements and attributes can be cased to string:

```
var_dump((string)$merchant->prod[0]);         ---   string(10) "product #1"
var_dump((string)$merchant->prod[0]['id']);   ---   string(9) "690579815"
```

Which is most often the actual information you're looking for. When you use `echo` or similar, this string-casting is done automatically btw.

```
echo $merchant->prod[0]; // prints: "product #1"
```

Similar to arrays (and object), you can also iterate over each **SimpleXMLElement**. For example the `$merchant` element:

```
foreach ($merchant as $children)
{
    echo $children->asXML(), "\n";
}
```

Gives:

```
<merchant id="1" name="companyname">
        <prod id="690579815" lang="en" pre_order="no" web_offer="yes" in_stock="yes">product #1</prod>
        <prod id="250544605" lang="en" pre_order="no" web_offer="yes" in_stock="yes">product #2</prod>
        <prod id="360355798" lang="en" pre_order="no" web_offer="yes" in_stock="yes">product #3</prod>
</merchant>
```

Which is a single element. So more interesting this is with named child-elements:

```
foreach ($merchant->prod as $prod)
{
    echo $prod->asXML(), "\n";
}
```

This now gives all children named *prod* one after the other:

```
<prod id="690579815" lang="en" pre_order="no" web_offer="yes" in_stock="yes">product #1</prod>
<prod id="250544605" lang="en" pre_order="no" web_offer="yes" in_stock="yes">product #2</prod>
<prod id="360355798" lang="en" pre_order="no" web_offer="yes" in_stock="yes">product #3</prod>
```

You find this as well explained in [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) in the PHP manual. Consult it as another source.

Just take these rules:

- `print_r` and `var_dump` cheat on you when used with **SimpleXMLElement**
- You don't need an array when you've got a **SimpleXMLElement** already
- In case **SimpleXMLElement** is too simple in data-access, it's sister [DOM library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) can be used easily as you can [switch over to it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28927960/367456).

[See the full example](http://3v4l.org/HuLc7).

Answer (score 0):

To access it as associative array, do this:

```
$data = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);
```

then you can access it like this:

```
count($data['merchant']['prod'])
```

Comment: I think this way, as it's more like the arrays I'm used to.  How would I access the value **690579815**?

Comment: That's why I proposed it. Access that value by `$data['merchant']['prod'][0]['id]`

Comment: @lee, you can't using this method, but you _can_ using the data as a `SimpleXMLElement` [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28916686/1230836) on how to access node attributes

Comment: Thanks Elias! I used the following and it worked: $data->merchant->prod[0]->attributes()->id

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleXMLElement` is an object, so you also need to access them as an object:

```
print count($data->merchant->prod);
```